# <initializer_list> in Cython

Tags: cython

Can `<initializer_list>`s be directly declared for use in Cython constructors?

As I understand, this is possible:

```
# Cython
cdef int[3] li = [1, 2, 3]  

# C++
int[3] li = {1, 2, 3}
```

But similar syntax for the `std::vector` class like

```
cdef vector[int] * li = new vector[int]([1,2,3])
```

that uses the [`<initializer_list>` constructor (6)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) seems unsupported by [`libcpp.vector`](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/libcpp/vector.pxd).

Can one declare Cython constructors like the one above, in which `[1, 2, 3]` is interpreted as `<initializer_list>`? If so, how?

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: My question was about the possibility of declaring constructors that use initializer_list syntax (`{}`). I updated the question to clarify that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is "no". Don't have any good suggestions for a workaround either

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of Cython states that this syntax is [not supported](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#c-variable-and-type-definitions):

```
cdef int[3] li = [1, 2, 3]
```

Please look at this section of the documentation:

```
def func():
    cdef int i = 10, j, k
    cdef float f = 2.5
    # cdef float g[4] = [1,2,3,4]  # currently not supported
    cdef float *g = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    cdef float *h = &f
```

Maybe this can help you...